# Split text: make some go left, and some right

Tags: html, css

I have a list, with list elements containing some text that I want to split like this:

|Foo..............Bar|

Where | denotes the edge of the element, and . denotes whitespace. My code looks like this:

```
<li><span class="left">Foo</span><span class="right">Bar</span></li>
```

Unfortunately, that's as far as I can go. I've tried using `position: relative; right: 1px;` and `float: right;` for `.right`, and neither work.

EDIT: neither does `text-align`.

EDIT 2: clarification: so I need some text to be aligned to the left, and some to the right.

Comment: Have you tried changing the width of the `<li>` element? If you float it to one side, you are just hitting the edge of the list item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<li><span class="left">Foo</span><span class="right">Bar</span></li>
```

CSS:

```
.left{
    float:left;
}

.right{
    float:right;
}

li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And you can define how big the space between Foo and Bar will be just by setting `width:50%` to the percentage you want.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tCfWr/2/)

Answer (score 2):

css

this makes the `li` full screen wide

```
li
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

float `.left` to the left and `.right` to the right

```
.left
{
    float: left
}

.right
{
    float: right;
}
```

then finally

```
li:after
{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```